# Asp.net MVC published website under IIS 7 showing blank page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

Yesterday i deployed a site in IIS with .Net framework 4.5, and it was returning back blank page without telling me any information about whats wrong. This website was working fine in my development environment. I further noticed that in global.ascx.cs i handled all errors in the following event

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();

    var logger = LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType());
    logger.Error("Application_Error", exception);

    var httpContext = ((MvcApplication)sender).Context;
    var currentController = " ";
    var currentAction = " ";
    RouteData currentRouteData = null;
    try
    {
        currentRouteData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));
    }
    catch { }

    if (currentRouteData != null)
    {
        if (currentRouteData.Values["controller"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString()))
        {
            currentController = currentRouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        }

        if (currentRouteData.Values["action"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString()))
        {
            currentAction = currentRouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
        }
    }

    var controller = new ErrorController();
    var routeData = new RouteData();
    var action = "Index";

    if (exception is HttpException)
    {
        var httpEx = exception as HttpException;
        if (httpEx.GetHttpCode() == 404)
        {
            action = "NotFound";

        }
        if (httpEx.GetHttpCode() == 404 && httpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
        {
            action = "NotFoundAjax";
        }
        // others if any
    }

    httpContext.ClearError();
    httpContext.Response.Clear();
    httpContext.Response.StatusCode = exception is HttpException ? ((HttpException)exception).GetHttpCode() : 500;
    httpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

    routeData.Values["controller"] = "Error";
    routeData.Values["action"] = action;

    controller.ViewData.Model = new HandleErrorInfo(exception, currentController, currentAction);
    ((IController)controller).Execute(new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), routeData));
}
```

After then I commented above code and deployed site again, it showed me the missing dlls errors

1. System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll
2. System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll
3. System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll
4. System.Web.Http.dll

I copied these dlls and it started to work. Finally i uncommented the application_error code to log the errors.

Is there a better way to know about compilation errors if we do not want to comment the global.ascx.cs application_error event?

Comment: How you deployed your site? Did you publish your site through Vistual studio?

Comment: To be honest I don't know why it happened, but in the development environment/process you should already see this kind of errors like missing DDL's.

Comment: @Amit, yes i published using visual studio.

Comment: @Eru there would be something missing on the server comparing to my development environment that resulted missing dlls and i have not figured out yet and expecting to know if someone already experienced this issue with explanation.

Comment: Have you referred these dll properly in your solutions using add reference? Does your publish have these dlls?

Comment: @Amit These dlls are part of the project by default and are CopyLocal=false

Comment: Is your website running on .net 4.0? Is your apppool set to run for 4.0?